# Как лучше смоделировать систему тегов на веб-сайте (модель данных в СУБД)

Tags: phpmyadmin, модель-данных, реляционная-модель

Есть несколько сущностей - товаров. Они качественно разные: tshirts (футболки), badges (значки) и т.д. Для каждой создал отдельную таблицу. Также создал таблицу genres (жанры), product_types (где каждая запись эквивалентна типу товара).
В таблице tags есть поля product_id, product_type_id и genre_id. Последние два поля - внешние ключи. Как быть с product_id?

Тут же появляется проблема, что вручную вписывать - такой себе вариант, как минимум, могут возникнуть ошибки из-за того, что туда могут вписать id, превышающий максимальное значение, да и в целом как-то не по-человечески получается.

Как спроектировать более подходяще?

P.S.
Для справки: помимо перечисленных таблиц в системе существуют и другие, но это не относится к теме вопроса.
Использую СУБД PhpMyAdmin из OpenServer.

Comment: По идее у Вас должна быть pivot таблица по типу `product_tags`, где будет внешний ключ `product_id` и `tag_id`. Потому что, если я верно понял, то это связь многие ко многим, разве не так? Не совсем понимаю зачем в таблице `tags` вообще хранить кучу данных о продукте.

Comment: Либо что такое `tag` в Вашем понимании?

Comment: @Simon , суть в том, что у многих товаров может быть несколько жанров сразу. Но товары разнородны, они бывают разных видов, а не только одного, как, скажем, книги. Упираюсь в проблему с product_id, т.к. он может быть из разных таблиц сразу: и из tshirts и из badges и т.д.
Ну вообще, сейчас на ум пришло сделать таблицу tags для каждой сущности отдельно: badges_tags, tshirts_tags. Вроде проблему решает, не знаю, конечно, насколько разумна моя идея, только-только учусь проектировать, поэтому и задаю здесь вопрос.

Comment: Ну так сделайте таблицу `product_genres`, если может быть много жанров сразу. Делать отдельную таблицу для каждого типа товара (значек, футболка, книга) -- немного странно, не находите? Я конечно не совсем понимаю какую цель Вы преследуете в итоге, но если у Вас к примеру интернет магазин, у Вас же не будет отдельной таблицы под каждый отдельный тип товара, потому что это будет ад, прибавьте туда еще отдельную таблицу для тегов каждого типа товара, в чем суть? Можете поискать различные примеры схем БД, [например](https://drawsql.app/templates)

Comment: @Simon , спасибо за ссылку. Вообще, идея сделать отдельные таблицы под каждый тип товара мне пришла, потому что каждый товар имеет вообще разные характеристики. Если их заносить в одну таблицу, то в итоге слишком много полей, большинство из которых в записи остаются пустыми, плюс, не совсем удобно их пытаться унифицировать. Ну а категорий товаров всё равно больше 4-х не будет с развитием ИС.
Тем не менее, после вашего сообщения, мне стало казаться, что это, видимо, всё равно сомнительное решение даже для моего случая...

Comment: @Simon , да, проблема в том, что изначально неправильно спроектирована база всё же (под каждый вид товара отдельная таблица). Спасибо.